# Index with multiple match (Loop) when one of the Match is a Date ( VBA ) - Value Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match, excel-2016

Hi I am trying to do index match Loop through Columns first and then Rows with multiple criteria in VBA

My Source data is like:

Date      email-ID    Attendance Status

And destination data like:

Email-id     Date1   date2   date3

Where as i am using Code with Worksheet function

```
.With Destination
.Range("B2:D4").Clear
For R = 2 To 4
For C = 2 To UBound(Arr2, 2)

.Cells(R, C) = 

.Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Source. Range("A2:C30000"),.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells   R, 1) & CDate(.Cells(1, C)), WS1.Range("B2:B30000") & WS1.Range("A2:A30000"), 0), 3)


Next C


Next R
.Activate
End With


End Sub
```

it is giving me Type Mismatch Error. Any help?

I am using Excel 2016 on Mac.

Comment: .Application.WorksheetFunction  ? Are you sure there is a "." before? Can you format your code properly please?

Comment: Also, worth mentioning which line throws the error.

Comment: you forgot at least the "()" on your function line for: `.Cells   R, 1`

Comment: And why is there a "." in `.With`?